# Qt - Cannot use external library for cross compiling

Tags: c++, qt, cross-platform

I follow this document [Cross Compile Qt - Raspberry](https://github.com/Kukkimonsuta/rpi-buildqt), and it works completly. I can cross compile simple application from qt creator. Now i want to use external libary ([ID3lib](http://id3lib.sourceforge.net/)). But it gets error when build project

> /home/shymaxtic/Documents/FPT/Hihi/ID3tag/lib/libid3.so: error: error adding symbols: File format not recognized.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Is the library compiled for your target?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Kuba Ober pointed, in order to include on you board a external library, you need to cross compile it, just like you do for your application.

Depending on the size of the library, you can either integrate it in your Qt project by creating a top level `SUBDIR` project, or simply cross-compile it manually, and provide the path to the cross-compiled library like you did here with `LIBS += -L<path> -l<library>`

When cross compiling, make sure to use the toolchain specific for your board (you already have it for Qt), and not the gcc/g++ of your desktop distribution